# Remove duplicates with least row ids from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a database table which looks like

| ID | Book_no | Book_name | Book_category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 1 | B1 | CB1 |
| ID1 | 2 | B1 | CB1 |
| ID1 | 3 | B2 | CB1 |
| ID1 | 4 | B2 | CB1 |
| ID1 | 5 | B3 | CB1 |
| ID2 | 1 | B1 | CB2 |
| ID2 | 2 | B1 | CB2 |
| ID2 | 3 | B2 | CB2 |

And the expected result is like

| ID | Book_No | Book_name | Book_category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 2 | B1 | CB1 |
| ID1 | 4 | B2 | CB1 |
| ID1 | 5 | B3 | CB1 |
| ID2 | 2 | B1 | CB2 |
| ID2 | 3 | B2 | CB2 |

I want to delete duplicate records from table on the basis of `ID`, `Book_name` and `Book_category`. Below query deletes the duplicate records, but the result is not expected one. As I want to delete all the duplicate records except the highest Book_no. Want to maintain the highest Book_no and delete all other duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? Do you want a `select` query that gives the "expected result", or do you want a `delete` statement that will "remove" the rows from your table permanently?

Comment: Want to delete duplicate records from table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `DELETE` correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT rid
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROWID AS rid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY id, book_name, book_category
             ORDER BY book_no DESC
           ) AS rn
    FROM table_name
  )
  WHERE  rn > 1
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, book_no, book_name, book_category) AS
SELECT 'ID1', 1, 'B1', 'CB1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID1', 2, 'B1', 'CB1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID1', 3, 'B2', 'CB1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID1', 4, 'B2', 'CB1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID1', 5, 'B3', 'CB1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID2', 1, 'B1', 'CB2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID2', 2, 'B1', 'CB2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID2', 3, 'B2', 'CB2' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the remaining rows are:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

> | ID | BOOK_NO | BOOK_NAME | BOOK_CATEGORY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ID1 | 2 | B1 | CB1 |
> | ID1 | 4 | B2 | CB1 |
> | ID1 | 5 | B3 | CB1 |
> | ID2 | 2 | B1 | CB2 |
> | ID2 | 3 | B2 | CB2 |

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/411e9c/5)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and filter where the name changes:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(book_name) over (partition by id, book_category order by book_no) as next_book_name
      from t
     ) t
where next_book_name is null or next_book_name <> book_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table looks like this:

```
create table books (id, book_no, book_name, book_category) as
  select 'ID1', 1, 'B1', 'CB1' from dual union all
  select 'ID1', 2, 'B1', 'CB1' from dual union all
  select 'ID1', 3, 'B2', 'CB1' from dual union all
  select 'ID1', 4, 'B2', 'CB1' from dual union all
  select 'ID1', 5, 'B3', 'CB1' from dual union all
  select 'ID2', 1, 'B1', 'CB2' from dual union all
  select 'ID2', 2, 'B1', 'CB2' from dual union all
  select 'ID2', 3, 'B2', 'CB2' from dual
;
```

You can use a `delete` statement in which you compare each row to the ones you want to keep. The ones you want to keep have `max(book_no)` when grouped by the other columns. So:

```
delete from books
where  (id, book_no, book_name, book_category) not in
         (
           select id, max(book_no), book_name, book_category
           from   books
           group  by id, book_name, book_category
         )
;
```

This assumes that the columns are non-null; if you may have `null` in the table, you will need to rewrite this a little more carefully, with a `not exists` condition instead of `not in`, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use first_value for finding the required id and can remove others using delete.

SELECT DISTINCT a.*, FIRST_VALUE(a.book_name)
OVER (ORDER BY a.book_name DESC
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
AS "HIGHEST"
FROM ( select * from books group by id, Book_name, book_category ) a;

SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(column_name)
OVER (ORDER BY column_name DESC
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
AS "HIGHEST"
FROM (select * from tables group by "column_names_to_be_grouped");